# Windows 8 boot issue after installing Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, multi-boot, bcdedit

After multi-boot installing Ubuntu, my Windows 8 will not boot anymore.

I can enter the System Repair interface and open a command line. But when I execute the `bcdedit` command, it says :

```
X:\windows\system32>bcdedit
The boot configuration data store could not be opened
The system cannot find the file specified
```

I spent hours on the Internet searching for solutions but could not find any satisfying answer.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to get an Ubuntu live USB, boot from it, then install `boot-repair` (you can read the [wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) first), and apply it's recommended repairs.

If this doesn't work, I recommend using a windows 8 cd/dvd/usb, boot from it, repair windows boot (not the entire system) - don't mind if it removes grub. Then boot from the ubuntu usb, and apply boot-repair on the drive.

Your problems are probably caused by UEFI bios in your computer, you should check on [how to install ubuntu alongside windows on a uefi system](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=install%20ubuntu%20windows%208%20uefi&t=ffab&atb=v124-2__&ia=web).